# Exterior derivative of a vector valued function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I'm trying to understand the exterior derivative in the simplest context that I can. I feel like I understand how an exterior derivative should behave for a function. For example, let's take a simple function:

$$ f(x^1, x^2) = 3x^1 + sin(x^2) $$

Here we can find the exterior derivative as shown:

$$ df = {\partial f \over \partial x^1 } dx^1 + {\partial f \over \partial x^2 } dx^2 = 3dx^1 + cos(x^2) dx^2  $$

Now we have a differential form, which we generated from the function.

I was wondering if we could also use the exterior derivative on a vector field in $\mathbb R^2 $ in the same way.

### Question

So if I have another function defined so that:

$$ f(x^1, x^2) = (x^1 + x^2) \mathbf{e_1} + ( x^1 x^2 ) \mathbf{e_2} \quad where \quad \mathbf{e_i} = {\partial f \over \partial x_i } $$

Could I still take its exterior derivative in the same way? I figured that if I treat each component as a separte function, so I have:

$$ f(x^1, x^2) = f^1(x^1, x^2) \mathbf{e_1} + f^2(x^1, x^2) \mathbf{e_2} $$

I can treat each component as a function and find a differential form for each, but then I realised that the basis vectors would have to come into play here.

Using the linearity of the $d$ operator (and leaving out the arguments to the functions), it should be true that:

$$ df = d( f^1 \mathbf{e_1} + f^2 \mathbf{e_2} ) \\df = d(f^1 \mathbf{e_1}) + d(f^2 \mathbf{e_2} ) $$

Then using the Leibniz property, I'd get:

$$ d(f^1 e_1) = d(f^1) \mathbf{e_1} + f^1 d(\mathbf{e_1}) $$

So then the question becomes:

> Does the exterior derivative of a basis vector make sense? So is:
>   $$ d(\mathbf{e_1}) $$
>   Well defined? If so, could I expand it in terms of the partial derivatives of $x^i$ to write:
>   $$ d(\mathbf{e^i}) = {\partial \mathbf{e_i} \over \partial x^i } dx^i $$

Comment: I presume you're using $\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2$ for the *standard orthonormal basis* for $\Bbb R^2$. In this case, they are constant vectors and you just differentiate the coordinate functions $f^i$.

Comment: I’m not assuming they are orthonormal. I’m interested in the case where they are not (like the unnormalised polar coordinates).